# Optimizing a regular expression to parse chinese pinyin

Tags: regex, optimization

I have a working regular expression to parse PinYin which matches every valid PinYin and does not match invalid ones. I am wondering how I can optimize it.

```
^(?P<initial>ch|zh|sh|r|c|b|d|g|f|h|k|j|m|l|n|q|p|s|t|w|y|x|z|)
 (?P<final>
   (?:(?<=ch)uang|(?<=ch)ang|(?<=ch)eng|(?<=ch)ong|(?<=ch)uai|(?<=ch)uan|(?<=ch)ai|(?<=ch)an|(?<=ch)ao|(?<=ch)en|(?<=ch)ou|(?<=ch)ua|(?<=ch)ui|(?<=ch)un|(?<=ch)uo|(?<=ch)a|(?<=ch)e|(?<=ch)i|(?<=ch)u)
  |(?:(?<=zh)uang|(?<=zh)ang|(?<=zh)eng|(?<=zh)ong|(?<=zh)uai|(?<=zh)uan|(?<=zh)ai|(?<=zh)an|(?<=zh)ao|(?<=zh)ei|(?<=zh)en|(?<=zh)ou|(?<=zh)ua|(?<=zh)ui|(?<=zh)un|(?<=zh)uo|(?<=zh)a|(?<=zh)e|(?<=zh)i|(?<=zh)u)
  |(?:(?<=sh)uang|(?<=sh)ang|(?<=sh)eng|(?<=sh)uai|(?<=sh)uan|(?<=sh)ai|(?<=sh)an|(?<=sh)ao|(?<=sh)ei|(?<=sh)en|(?<=sh)ou|(?<=sh)ua|(?<=sh)ui|(?<=sh)un|(?<=sh)uo|(?<=sh)a|(?<=sh)e|(?<=sh)i|(?<=sh)u)
  |(?:(?<=c)ang|(?<=c)eng|(?<=c)ong|(?<=c)uan|(?<=c)ai|(?<=c)an|(?<=c)ao|(?<=c)en|(?<=c)ou|(?<=c)ui|(?<=c)un|(?<=c)uo|(?<=c)a|(?<=c)e|(?<=c)i|(?<=c)u)
  |(?:(?<=b)ang|(?<=b)eng|(?<=b)ian|(?<=b)iao|(?<=b)ing|(?<=b)ai|(?<=b)an|(?<=b)ao|(?<=b)ei|(?<=b)en|(?<=b)ie|(?<=b)in|(?<=b)a|(?<=b)i|(?<=b)o|(?<=b)u)
  |(?:(?<=d)ang|(?<=d)eng|(?<=d)ian|(?<=d)iao|(?<=d)ing|(?<=d)ong|(?<=d)uan|(?<=d)ai|(?<=d)an|(?<=d)ao|(?<=d)ei|(?<=d)en|(?<=d)ia|(?<=d)ie|(?<=d)iu|(?<=d)ou|(?<=d)ui|(?<=d)un|(?<=d)uo|(?<=d)a|(?<=d)e|(?<=d)i|(?<=d)u)
  |(?:(?<!r|c|b|d|g|f|h|k|j|m|l|n|q|p|s|t|w|y|x|z)a|(?<!r|c|b|d|g|f|h|k|j|m|l|n|q|p|s|t|w|y|x|z)ai
  |(?<!r|c|b|d|g|f|h|k|j|m|l|n|q|p|s|t|w|y|x|z)an|(?<!r|c|b|d|g|f|h|k|j|m|l|n|q|p|s|t|w|y|x|z)ang
  |(?<!r|c|b|d|g|f|h|k|j|m|l|n|q|p|s|t|w|y|x|z)ao|(?<!r|c|b|d|g|f|h|k|j|m|l|n|q|p|s|t|w|y|x|z)e
```

Above is an abbreviated version for sake of readability. The whole expression can be found at the end of this post.

I am specifically wondering if passing in two or more prefixes to an ending matcher would improve perfomance:

```
 (<=ch|zh|sh)uang|(<=ch|zh|sh)ang...
```

Thanks for your time and suggestions.

whole regex:

```
 ^(?P<initial>ch|zh|sh|r|c|b|d|g|f|h|k|j|m|l|n|q|p|s|t|w|y|x|z|)(?P<final>(?:(?<=ch)uang|(?<=ch)ang|(?<=ch)eng|(?<=ch)ong|(?<=ch)uai|(?<=ch)uan|(?<=ch)ai|(?<=ch)an|(?<=ch)ao|(?<=ch)en|(?<=ch)ou|(?<=ch)ua|(?<=ch)ui|(?<=ch)un|(?<=ch)uo|(?<=ch)a|(?<=ch)e|(?<=ch)i|(?<=ch)u)|(?:(?<=zh)uang|(?<=zh)ang|(?<=zh)eng|(?<=zh)ong|(?<=zh)uai|(?<=zh)uan|(?<=zh)ai|(?<=zh)an|(?<=zh)ao|(?<=zh)ei|(?<=zh)en|(?<=zh)ou|(?<=zh)ua|(?<=zh)ui|(?<=zh)un|(?<=zh)uo|(?<=zh)a|(?<=zh)e|(?<=zh)i|(?<=zh)u)|(?:(?<=sh)uang|(?<=sh)ang|(?<=sh)eng|(?<=sh)uai|(?<=sh)uan|(?<=sh)ai|(?<=sh)an|(?<=sh)ao|(?<=sh)ei|(?<=sh)en|(?<=sh)ou|(?<=sh)ua|(?<=sh)ui|(?<=sh)un|(?<=sh)uo|(?<=sh)a|(?<=sh)e|(?<=sh)i|(?<=sh)u)|(?:(?<=c)ang|(?<=c)eng|(?<=c)ong|(?<=c)uan|(?<=c)ai|(?<=c)an|(?<=c)ao|(?<=c)en|(?<=c)ou|(?<=c)ui|(?<=c)un|(?<=c)uo|(?<=c)a|(?<=c)e|(?<=c)i|(?<=c)u)|(?:(?<=b)ang|(?<=b)eng|(?<=b)ian|(?<=b)iao|(?<=b)ing|(?<=b)ai|(?<=b)an|(?<=b)ao|(?<=b)ei|(?<=b)en|(?<=b)ie|(?<=b)in|(?<=b)a|(?<=b)i|(?<=b)o|(?<=b)u)|(?:(?<=d)ang|(?<=d)eng|(?<=d)ian|(?<=d)iao|(?<=d)ing|(?<=d)ong|(?<=d)uan|(?<=d)ai|(?<=d)an|(?<=d)ao|(?<=d)ei|(?<=d)en|(?<=d)ia|(?<=d)ie|(?<=d)iu|(?<=d)ou|(?<=d)ui|(?<=d)un|(?<=d)uo|(?<=d)a|(?<=d)e|(?<=d)i|(?<=d)u)|(?:(?<=g)uang|(?<=g)ang|(?<=g)eng|(?<=g)ong|(?<=g)uai|(?<=g)uan|(?<=g)ai|(?<=g)an|(?<=g)ao|(?<=g)ei|(?<=g)en|(?<=g)ou|(?<=g)ua|(?<=g)ui|(?<=g)un|(?<=g)uo|(?<=g)a|(?<=g)e|(?<=g)u)|(?:(?<=f)ang|(?<=f)eng|(?<=f)iao|(?<=f)an|(?<=f)ei|(?<=f)en|(?<=f)ou|(?<=f)a|(?<=f)o|(?<=f)u)|(?:(?<!sh|ch|zh)(?<=h)uang|(?<!sh|ch|zh)(?<=h)ang|(?<!sh|ch|zh)(?<=h)eng|(?<!sh|ch|zh)(?<=h)ong|(?<!sh|ch|zh)(?<=h)uai|(?<!sh|ch|zh)(?<=h)uan|(?<!sh|ch|zh)(?<=h)ai|(?<!sh|ch|zh)(?<=h)an|(?<!sh|ch|zh)(?<=h)ao|(?<!sh|ch|zh)(?<=h)ei|(?<!sh|ch|zh)(?<=h)en|(?<!sh|ch|zh)(?<=h)ou|(?<!sh|ch|zh)(?<=h)ua|(?<!sh|ch|zh)(?<=h)ui|(?<!sh|ch|zh)(?<=h)un|(?<!sh|ch|zh)(?<=h)uo|(?<!sh|ch|zh)(?<=h)a|(?<!sh|ch|zh)(?<=h)e|(?<!sh|ch|zh)(?<=h)u)|(?:(?<=k)uang|(?<=k)ang|(?<=k)eng|(?<=k)ong|(?<=k)uai|(?<=k)uan|(?<=k)ai|(?<=k)an|(?<=k)ao|(?<=k)en|(?<=k)ou|(?<=k)ua|(?<=k)ui|(?<=k)un|(?<=k)uo|(?<=k)a|(?<=k)e|(?<=k)u)|(?:(?<=j)iang|(?<=j)iong|(?<=j)ian|(?<=j)iao|(?<=j)ing|(?<=j)üan|(?<=j)ia|(?<=j)ie|(?<=j)in|(?<=j)iu|(?<=j)üe|(?<=j)ün|(?<=j)i|(?<=j)ü)|(?:(?<=m)ang|(?<=m)eng|(?<=m)ian|(?<=m)iao|(?<=m)ing|(?<=m)ai|(?<=m)an|(?<=m)ao|(?<=m)ei|(?<=m)en|(?<=m)ie|(?<=m)in|(?<=m)iu|(?<=m)ou|(?<=m)a|(?<=m)e|(?<=m)i|(?<=m)o|(?<=m)u)|(?:(?<=l)iang|(?<=l)ang|(?<=l)eng|(?<=l)ian|(?<=l)iao|(?<=l)ing|(?<=l)ong|(?<=l)uan|(?<=l)ai|(?<=l)an|(?<=l)ao|(?<=l)ei|(?<=l)ia|(?<=l)ie|(?<=l)in|(?<=l)iu|(?<=l)ou|(?<=l)un|(?<=l)uo|(?<=l)üe|(?<=l)a|(?<=l)e|(?<=l)i|(?<=l)o|(?<=l)u|(?<=l)ü)|(?:(?<=n)iang|(?<=n)ang|(?<=n)eng|(?<=n)ian|(?<=n)iao|(?<=n)ing|(?<=n)ong|(?<=n)uan|(?<=n)ai|(?<=n)an|(?<=n)ao|(?<=n)ei|(?<=n)en|(?<=n)ie|(?<=n)in|(?<=n)iu|(?<=n)ou|(?<=n)un|(?<=n)uo|(?<=n)üe|(?<=n)a|(?<=n)e|(?<=n)i|(?<=n)u|(?<=n)ü)|(?:(?<=q)iang|(?<=q)iong|(?<=q)ian|(?<=q)iao|(?<=q)ing|(?<=q)üan|(?<=q)ia|(?<=q)ie|(?<=q)in|(?<=q)iu|(?<=q)üe|(?<=q)ün|(?<=q)i|(?<=q)ü)|(?:(?<=p)ang|(?<=p)eng|(?<=p)ian|(?<=p)iao|(?<=p)ing|(?<=p)ai|(?<=p)an|(?<=p)ao|(?<=p)ei|(?<=p)en|(?<=p)ie|(?<=p)in|(?<=p)ou|(?<=p)a|(?<=p)i|(?<=p)o|(?<=p)u)|(?:(?<=s)ang|(?<=s)eng|(?<=s)ong|(?<=s)uan|(?<=s)ai|(?<=s)an|(?<=s)ao|(?<=s)en|(?<=s)ou|(?<=s)ui|(?<=s)un|(?<=s)uo|(?<=s)a|(?<=s)e|(?<=s)i|(?<=s)u)|(?:(?<=r)ang|(?<=r)eng|(?<=r)ong|(?<=r)uan|(?<=r)an|(?<=r)ao|(?<=r)en|(?<=r)ou|(?<=r)ua|(?<=r)ui|(?<=r)un|(?<=r)uo|(?<=r)e|(?<=r)i|(?<=r)u)|(?:(?<=t)ang|(?<=t)eng|(?<=t)ian|(?<=t)iao|(?<=t)ing|(?<=t)ong|(?<=t)uan|(?<=t)ai|(?<=t)an|(?<=t)ao|(?<=t)ei|(?<=t)ie|(?<=t)ou|(?<=t)ui|(?<=t)un|(?<=t)uo|(?<=t)a|(?<=t)e|(?<=t)i|(?<=t)u)|(?:(?<=w)ang|(?<=w)eng|(?<=w)ai|(?<=w)an|(?<=w)ei|(?<=w)en|(?<=w)a|(?<=w)o|(?<=w)u)|(?:(?<=y)ang|(?<=y)ing|(?<=y)ong|(?<=y)uan|(?<=y)ai|(?<=y)an|(?<=y)ao|(?<=y)in|(?<=y)ou|(?<=y)ue|(?<=y)un|(?<=y)a|(?<=y)e|(?<=y)e|(?<=y)i|(?<=y)o|(?<=y)u)|(?:(?<=x)iang|(?<=x)iong|(?<=x)ian|(?<=x)iao|(?<=x)ing|(?<=x)üan|(?<=x)ia|(?<=x)ie|(?<=x)in|(?<=x)iu|(?<=x)üe|(?<=x)ün|(?<=x)i|(?<=x)ü)|(?:(?<=z)ang|(?<=z)eng|(?<=z)ong|(?<=z)uan|(?<=z)ai|(?<=z)an|(?<=z)ao|(?<=z)ei|(?<=z)en|(?<=z)ou|(?<=z)ui|(?<=z)un|(?<=z)uo|(?<=z)a|(?<=z)e|(?<=z)i|(?<=z)u)|(?:(?<!r|c|b|d|g|f|h|k|j|m|l|n|q|p|s|t|w|y|x|z)a|(?<!r|c|b|d|g|f|h|k|j|m|l|n|q|p|s|t|w|y|x|z)ai|(?<!r|c|b|d|g|f|h|k|j|m|l|n|q|p|s|t|w|y|x|z)an|(?<!r|c|b|d|g|f|h|k|j|m|l|n|q|p|s|t|w|y|x|z)ang|(?<!r|c|b|d|g|f|h|k|j|m|l|n|q|p|s|t|w|y|x|z)ao|(?<!r|c|b|d|g|f|h|k|j|m|l|n|q|p|s|t|w|y|x|z)e|(?<!r|c|b|d|g|f|h|k|j|m|l|n|q|p|s|t|w|y|x|z)ei|(?<!r|c|b|d|g|f|h|k|j|m|l|n|q|p|s|t|w|y|x|z)en|(?<!r|c|b|d|g|f|h|k|j|m|l|n|q|p|s|t|w|y|x|z)eng|(?<!r|c|b|d|g|f|h|k|j|m|l|n|q|p|s|t|w|y|x|z)er|(?<!r|c|b|d|g|f|h|k|j|m|l|n|q|p|s|t|w|y|x|z)o|(?<!r|c|b|d|g|f|h|k|j|m|l|n|q|p|s|t|w|y|x|z)ou))$
```

Comment: ^ programming language that is, i stared at that question for a couple minutes before i got it haha - could just be my Monday brain tho

Comment: what language do you use? are named groups needed?

Comment: I used pcre compliant synthax to use this RE in any language (and thereby avoid writing this code again and again) my target languages would python, go, C/C++ and javascript as of now. The named groups are not desperately needed, but I'd prefer keeping them.

Comment: You can exclude javascript that has not a pcre compliant regex engine and doesn't support lookbehinds

Comment: @flexy: JavaScript is not pcre-compatible. It neither supports named groups nor lookbehind.

Comment: thanks, I'm relatively new to javascript and wasn't aware of that

Comment: Interesting, what would you be using this for?

Comment: text parsing and input validation, mainly. I wrote programmatic parsers for this, but figured, that it might be better to do it like this.

Comment: I took a different approach when creating a pinyin regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736291/regex-for-matching-pinyin/20736292#20736292

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that your regex engine supports lookbehinds, atomic groups and possessive quantifiers (that are PCRE features):

#### Some examples of what can be replaced:

- all `(?:` by `(?>`
- the begining *(all the first named group)* by:

  `^(?P<initial>(?>[csz]h?+|[bdfghj-npqrtwxy])?)`
- this part* by:

  `|(?<![csz]h)(?<=h)(?>a(?>[io]|ng?+)?|e(?>i|ng?+)?|o(?>u|ng)|u(?>[ino]|a(?>i|ng?+)?)?)`

**( ie: `|(?:(?<!sh|ch|zh)(?<=h)uang|(?<!sh|ch|...|(?<!sh|ch|zh)(?<=h)u)` )*

- the last part* by:

  `|(?<![bcdfghj-np-tw-z])(?>a(?>[io]|ng?+)?|e(?>[ir]|ng?+)?|ou?+))$`

**( ie:`|(?:(?<!r|c|b|d|g|f|h|k|j|m|l|n|q|p|s|t|w|y|x|z)a|(?<!r|c|b|d|...))$` )*

#### How to deal with the other parts:

example:

```
(?:(?<=ch)uang|(?<=ch)ang|(?<=ch)eng|(?<=ch)ong|(?<=ch)uai|(?<=ch)uan|(?<=ch)ai|(?<=ch)an|(?<=ch)ao|(?<=ch)en|(?<=ch)ou|(?<=ch)ua|(?<=ch)ui|(?<=ch)un|(?<=ch)uo|(?<=ch)a|(?<=ch)e|(?<=ch)i|(?<=ch)u)
```

_ all this kind of parts has the same lookbehind, you must do these steps for each _

```
# step 1: lookarounds factorization

(?<=ch)(?>ang|eng|ong|uai|uan|ai|an|ao|en|ou|ua|ui|un|uo|a|e|i|u)

# step 2: sort all the content by alphabetic order 

(?<=ch)(?>a|ai|an|ang|ao|e|en|eng|i|ong|ou|u|ua|uai|uan|ui|un|uo)

# step 3: group by first letter: don't forget the ? if the letter can be alone

(?<=ch)(?>a(?>i|n|ng|o)?|e(?>n|ng)?|i|o(?>ng|u)|u(?>a|ai|an|i|n|o)?)

# step 4: reduce the terminations (ie: n & ng => ng?+) 

(?<=ch)(?>a(?>i|ng?+|o)?|e(?>ng?+)?|i|o(?>ng|u)|u(?>a[in]?+|i|n|o)?)

# step 5: put single letters in a character class

(?<=ch)(?>a(?>[io]|ng?+)?|e(?>ng?+)?|i|o(?>ng|u)|u(?>a[in]?+|[ino])?)
```

#### conclusion

Although the result is shorter, the goal here is optimization. I reduced the number of tests with the factorization and the number of backtracks using atomic groups and possessive quantifiers.

**some limitations**

Note that regex features like [atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) and [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) are not supported by all regex flavors, but it is possible to remedy the problem:

- for flavors that don't support possessive quantifiers: change `?+` to `?`
- for flavors that don't support atomic groups: change `(?>` to `(?:`

*(Note that there is a trick to have atomic groups with Python, which you may test with a timer, to surround all the pattern. See this incredible post: [Do Python regular expressions have an equivalent to Ruby's atomic grouping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577372/do-python-regular-expressions-have-an-equivalent-to-rubys-atomic-grouping))*

Some regex engines such as javascript do not support lookbehinds. In this case, you must rewrite all your pattern using only alternations (ie `|`), which isn't a bad thing, since lookbehinds make your pattern slower; and give up the named captures that are not supported too. *(In this context, it should be noted that to remove negative lookbehinds you need to put syllables described in these parts before all others so that they are matched first.)*

**other ways of optimization**

- rewrite your pattern without lookbehinds and with `|` instead
- sort the different lines by the most used syllables

Comment: +1 for very thorough, accurate, and nicely formatted response

Comment: Impressive! Thank you very much :-)