# Language detection for pinyin, translit etc?

Tags: internationalization, nlp, transliteration, indic

Real-world user-generated text in non-Latin alphabet languages is often not in canonical form but in [translit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translit), [shlyokavitsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Bulgarian#Informal_writing), [arabizi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_chat_alphabet), pinyin and so on.  Language detection software is starting to handle it [smartly](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/vot%20tak%20dolzhna%20byt'%20umnaya%20sistema), but usually it [doesn't work](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Chi%20ashxatum%2C%20apsos), even though it's technically fairly trivial to incorporate it.

[image]

Is there a language detection system that is handling these informal Latinisations well?  (Ideally a Python lib, but any language or service would be interesting.)

The Yandex, Microsoft and top Python lang id libs, like [langid](https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py), have nothing on this front.  Two that halfway work are known to me, both from Google:
- [CLD](https://github.com/CLD2Owners/cld2), which is [part of Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n#method-detectLanguage)
- [the Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest#detect-language)
Besides only recognising translit for a few top languages, they are not ideal for a variety of reasons (accuracy, performance, price...)

This is a major issue for major languages like Hindi, Persian, Chinese, Arabic and Russian, and for all the other languages not written in the Latin alphabet but commonly Latinised (Romanised) online.

Comment: You can detect pinyin with a regex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736291/regex-for-matching-pinyin/20736292#20736292

Comment: @ccpizza I need it for all langs.

Comment: In that case you'd probably need to roll out your own machine learning detector based on pre-trained models (like google does) or buy it as a service from a third party which has proper datasets.