# Using Regex to extract certain phrases but exclude phrases followed by the word "of"

Tags: python, regex, nlp, jupyter-notebook

I am basically trying to extract Section references from a long document.

The following code does so quite well:

```
example1 = 'Sections 21(1), 54(2), 78(1) of Harry Potter'
res = re.search(r'Sections?\W+(\w+)(\(\w+\))?(, (\w+)(\(\w+\))?)*', example1)
res.group(0)
```

Output: 'Sections 21(1), 54(2), 78(1)'

However, frequently the sections refer to outside books and I would like to either indicate those or exclude them. Generally, the section reference is followed by an "of" if it refers to another book (example below):

```
example2 = 'Sections 21(1), 54(2), 78(1) of Harry Potter'
```

So in this case, I would like to exclude these sections because they refer to Harry Potter and not to sections within the document. The following should achieve this but it doesn't work.

```
example2 = 'Sections 21(1), 54(2), 78(1) of Harry Potter'
res = re.search(r'Sections?(\W+(\w+)(\(\w+\))?(, (\w+)(\(\w+\))?)*)(?!\s+of)', example2)
res.group(0)
```

Expected output: `Sections 21(1), 54(2), 78` --> `(?!\s+of)` removes the `(1)` behind `78` but not the entire reference.

Comment: So what should be the end result?

Comment: Do you want to capture the 'Harry Potter' part here?

Comment: Your first and second example have the same input string.

Comment: If so, could you just use `Sections?(\W+.*of\s\w+\s\w+)` to capture the above pattern, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emulate atomic groups with capturing groups and lookahead:

```
(?=(?P<section>Sections?\W+(\w+)(\(\w+\))?(, (\w+)(\(\w+\))?)*))(?P=section)(?! of)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rEzaso/4/)

Long story short: 
  * in positive lookahead you create a capturing group called `section` that finds a section pattern
  * then you match the group contents in `(?P=secion)`
  * then in negative lookahead you check that there is no `of` following

Here is a [really good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13577411/580346) that explains that technique.

Comment: I am trying to use this with re.findall (since there are multiple references per section) but somehow it duplicates the answer in strange ways. 
example1 = 'Sections 23, 24 and 5'
res = re.findall(r'(?=(?P<section>Sections?\W+(\w+)(\(\w+\))?(, (\w+)(\(\w+\))?)*))(?P=section)(?! of)', example1)
Ouput: [('Sections 23, 24', '23', '', ', 24', '24', '')]

Comment: there are multiple capturing group in the regex, change them to non-capturing groups (use `(:?...)` instead of `(...)`)

Comment: I don't use "..." anywhere, right? Where exactly would I add (:?...)?

Comment: Yes, replace `(...)` with `(:?...)`

Comment: I meant in the regex. I [tried](https://regex101.com/r/rEzaso/5) but it does not work too good. You can also just choose the first element of the tuple that you have in the output (that's the full match).

Comment: One very last question (sorry for the bother): How would I accomodate for an "and", for example 'Sections 26(1), 51(1) and 62(1)"?

Comment: You can add it as alernative to a comma. Please use the regex101 to try it, I'm sure you'll manage :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because after `(?!\s+of)` fails, it backtracks before optional `(\(..\))?` which matches because negative lookahead doesn't match.

Atomic group could be used with other regex engines but isn't implemented in python `re`.

Other solution is to use a possessive quantifier `+` after `?` optional part :

```
r'Sections?(\W+(\w+)(\(\w+\))?(, (\w+)(\(\w+\))?+)*)(?!\s+of)'
```

note the `+` after `?`

Comment: Hmm did this work for you? Because I get the following error: multiple repeat at position 46

Comment: indeed, sadly, it doesn't work too with python [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/cIiRA1/1)