# Convert python search regex to ruby regex

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to convert the following python regex to ruby

```
match = re.search(r'window.__APOLLO_STATE__ = JSON.parse\("(.+?)"\);', body)
```

I've done some [digging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671653/ruby-regex-vs-python-regex/5672092) and Regexp#match should be what i'm looking for but the following is returning nil.

```
resp.body.match('^window.__APOLLO_STATE__ = JSON.parse\("(.+?)"\)')
```

How can I convert the regex and where am I wrong?

Comment: You probably want to pass a Regexp object to `match` rather than a string, i.e. `/^window.__APOLLO_.../`.

Comment: Do you need to get what is inside the quotes?

Comment: yes @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Use `resp.body[/window\.__APOLLO_STATE__ = JSON\.parse\("(.*?)"\);/, 1]`, see https://ideone.com/sJth9I

Comment: thank you @WiktorStribiżew :)

Comment: @user2954587 I posted a bit expanded answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
resp.body[/window\.__APOLLO_STATE__ = JSON\.parse\("(.*?)"\);/, 1]
```

Here,

- `/.../` is a regex literal notation that is very convenient when defining regex patterns
- Literal dots are escaped, else, they match any char but line break chars
- The `.+?` is changed to `.*?` to be able to match empty values (else, you may overmatch, it is easier to later discard empty matches than fix overmatches)
- `1` tells the engine to return the  value  of the capturing group with ID 2 of the first match. If you need multiple matches, use `resp.body.scan(/regex/)`.

Answer (score 0):

An idiomatic way is to use the `=~` regex match operator:

```
resp.body =~ /^window.__APOLLO_STATE__ = JSON.parse\("(.+?)"\)/
```

You can access the capture groups with `$1`, `$2`, and so on.

If you don't like the global variable usage, you can also use the `Regexp#match` method

```
result = /^window.__APOLLO_STATE__ = JSON.parse\("(.+?)"\)/.match(resp.body)
result[1] # => returns first capture group
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your string is something like

```
str = 'window.__APOLLO_STATE__ = JSON.parse("my dog has fleas");'
```

and you wish to extract the text between the double quotes. You can do that with the following regular expression, which does not employ a capture group:

```
r = /\Awindow\.__APOLLO_STATE__ = JSON\.parse\(\"\K.+?(?=\"\);\z)/
```

```
str[r]
  #=> "my dog has fleas"
```

The regular expression can be written in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting:

```
r = /
    \A          # match beginning of string
    window\.__APOLLO_STATE__\ =\ JSON\.parse\(\"
                # match substring
    \K          # discard everything matched so far 
    .+?         # match 1+ characters, lazily
    (?=\"\);\z) # match "); followed by end-of-string (positive lookahead)
    /x          # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

The contents of a *positive lookahead* must be matched but are not part of the match returned. Neither is the text matched prior to the `\K` directive part of the match returned.

Free-spacing mode removes all whitespace before the expression is parsed. Accordingly, any intended spaces (in `"APOLLO_STATE__ = JSON"`, for example) must be protected. I've done that by escaping the spaces, one of several ways that can be done.